# R simplify gsub() to make sample names from longer string

Tags: r, gsub, string-substitution

I have a list of sample names

```
name <- c("GOM_13M_TB-01_S.HM (Q)30",
"GOM_13M_PS-06_S.HM (Q)30",
"GOM_13O_PS-06_3C_HM (Q)30",
"GOM_14O_GI-02_B3 (Q)30",
"GOM_14O_PS-03_A3 (Q)30",
"GOM_12J_GI-01_MS (Q)30")'
```

that need to be simplified into

```
13M_TB-01_MS  (MS for consistency)
13M_PS-06_MS
13O_PS-06_3C  (I am not too concerned about the last 2 digits order)
14O_GI-02_B3
14O_PS-03_A3
12J_GI-01_MS
```

I have tried the following uses of gsub(), but I'm trying to simplify the solution.

```
x <- gsub("GOM_", "", name) 
x <- gsub("\\(Q\\)30", "", x)
x <- gsub("_S", "_MS", x)
x <- gsub(".HM", "", x)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote here. There's sample data, the attempted approach, the expected output. All very good for a first question at SO....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like the following:

```
gsub("GOM_(.*) .*", "\\1", gsub("S.HM", "MS", name))
# [1] "13M_TB-01_MS"    "13M_PS-06_MS"    "13O_PS-06_3C_HM" "14O_GI-02_B3"   
# [5] "14O_PS-03_A3"    "12J_GI-01_MS"
```

Or, perhaps:

```
## I think this matches what you're expecting...
substr(gsub("S.HM", "MS", name), 5, 16)
# [1] "13M_TB-01_MS" "13M_PS-06_MS" "13O_PS-06_3C" "14O_GI-02_B3"
# [5] "14O_PS-03_A3" "12J_GI-01_MS"
```

Comment: Getting there, [3] still has some issues, but its a lot closer.  Thanks.

Comment: That's great, I was trying to figure out what the code would be to exclude the first 4 digits in the string and modify the end.  Thanks!